# When I run chmod with C:\hadoop\bin\winutils.exe , it says “The aplication was unable to start correctly”

Tags: apache-spark

I’m trying to run the below command,

```
C:\hadoop\bin\winutils.exe chmod -R 777 C:\SparkProject
```

But it gives me error saying

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)

I have kept the winutils.exe in \hadoop\bin, also set up the environment variable for HADOOP_HOME.

If I run the spark program which writes in local system from intellij idea. it fails. But but I can see zero byte files are created in that folder (a .crc file).

I’m using windows 10.

Comment: Spark Code:
package com.sparkPractice
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
object testFile {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir" , "C:/hadoop")

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[1]").appName("partitionDemo").getOrCreate()
    println("trying to read the file .... ")
    val rddTest = spark.sparkContext.textFile("file:///SparkProject/rdd.txt")
    rddTest.collect().foreach(line => println(line))
    println("file has been loaded")

    rddTest.saveAsTextFile("file:///SparkProject/newRDD")
  }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried all the winutils available as I was not sure of the version that I need.
Finally I have downloaded one latest from GitHub for hadoop-3.3.0.

link: https://github.com/kontext-tech/winutils/blob/master/hadoop-3.3.0/bin/winutils.exe

And it's working now. I'm able to give permission via winutils.exe as well as write into local file system.